# Max value of nested array in hash

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

What I have:

```
hash = {id =>[string, number], id =>[string, number]}
```

I need to get the max value of number. I have been able to do this, but when I puts it.
I get:

```
id
string
number
```

What I need please

```
id string number
```

This is what I've tried:

This brings the max value to the top of list, but I need to exclude the rest of the list.

```
hash.each{|x, y| puts "#{x} #{y[0]} #{y[1]}"}.max
```

This returns the max value but displays it vertically

```
puts hash.max_by{|y| "#{y}"}
```

I have tried numerous other things and am having a hard time wrapping my head around this one.

Not sure if it matters but I am read this in from a file into a hash, the number is a float

Comment: I expect you realize that hashes have unique keys, and most readers probably know what your `hash` looks like, but you should write it like (for example) this: `hash = {id1 =>[string1, number1], id2 =>[string2, number2]}`.

Comment: K, thanks for the tip

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `max` here doesn’t do anything (since it is called on `hash` and its return value never used):

```
hash.each{|x, y| puts "#{x} #{y[0]} #{y[1]}"}.max
```

This is the same as doing `puts` on an array (since that’s what `max_by` returns), which prints each element on a separate line. You’re also unnecessarily converting your number to a string (which can result in unexpected comparison results):

```
puts hash.max_by{|y| "#{y}"}
```

Instead let’s just get the max key/value pair:

```
max = hash.max_by { |id, (string, number)| number }
#=> ["the-id", ["the-string", 3.14]]
```

Now we can `flatten` and `join` the array before `puts`-ing it:

```
puts max.flatten.join(' ')
# prints: the-id the-string 3.14
```

Comment: Wow! I didn't realize that in the block I could do                    |id,(string, number)|. Only problem is that I added new items with a higher number but with a lower index to the hash and what it is doing is giving me the max index instead of the value.

Comment: Sorry I mean with a lower "id" and a higher "number"

Comment: Thanks man you really helped me. I didn't realize that I could put the |id,(string, number)| in block like that. So this is what I did.     
    hash.each do |id,(string, number)|
      max = "#{id}. #{string}, #{number}"
    end
      puts max

Comment: You said “max value of number“ in your question, but your comment seems to contradict that. Stop using `each` when you can use a higher-order function. Your `each` in your comment will just get the last key inserted into `hash` (along with its value), not necessarily the max of anything.

Comment: @user2963093 No, it really doesn’t. See https://ideone.com/SaMvu4 for example. Note how the “max” value is in fact not in any way the max.

Comment: Your right. I figured it out. Thanks for all your help, it's greatly appreciated. I think I was a little confused because I was sorting on the way into hash from file and so that was throwing me off. Sorry to be such a noob.

Answer (score 0):

I would re-arrange the hash with `number` as the key, then use `sort_by()`: http://www.rubyinside.com/how-to/ruby-sort-hash